# Item from Menu act like a button

Tags: android, contextmenu, menuitem

i have an issue regarding a item from a menu to act like a Button, and i don't know how to solve it.

In a item from menu i refeer to a item expandable like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Item1" />
  <item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="Item2" />
</menu>
```

and i dont know how to define it, and use it like a button, like this:

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
      String uri=null;

      Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
      intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
                      RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
      if (uri !=null) {
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI,
                        Uri.parse(uri));        
      } else {
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI,
                        (Uri)null);
      }

      startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
  });
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking, could you re-write your question?

Comment: @Sam In my R.layout, i have a menu.xml with two items like this:

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
          android:title="Item1" />
    
    <item android:id="@+id/item2"
          android:title="Item2" />
</menu>
Instead of R.layout where in main.xml i have a defined a Button, in my Class wich extends Activity, i want that **item** to act like a Button, istead of **Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener)** i want that **item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener)**, but i cannot define it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to implement a menu.  For API 10 or lower, put menu.xml in res/menu/ and override these two functions in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:
        // Do something
        break;
    case R.id.item2:
        // Do something else
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For API 11+, consider using an action bar as [explained here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

**Update**

For Preferences menus you will want to use findPreference() and define a custom setOnPreferenceClickListener().  Rather than copying code snippets here, follow any of these three detailed tutorials:

- http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences
- http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/tag/ringtonepreference/
- http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android16Preferences.php

Comment: thanks, but i don't want to make an Options or a Context Menu, instead of these two, i want to make a Menu with Items to look like PreferenceActivity ` <RingtonePreference
                android:name="Ringtone Preference"
                android:summary="Select a ringtone"
                android:title="Ringtones"
                android:key="ringtonePref" /> `

Comment: Ok, like this image? http://androidpartaker.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/ringtone_preference.jpg

Comment: Acctualy, like this : [link](http://picz.ro/index.php?id=145e02ac4b9373e0dce5ec469d6e82f5)

Comment: usefull articles, but this is a old problem of mine: It works pretty well, but the ringtone won't change. (Don't write on phone settings or something).